# Multiple cells at same timestamp

Tags: hbase

I know that Hbase allows to store multiple values to a row using the concept of versioning.
My question is if I accidentally executed three writes to a given cell all with the same
version during which time no flushes have occurred. Which of the three data writes will dBase
maintain?

Answer (score 0):

No you cant set 2 values for a cell with same timestamp. But you can have 2 cells with same timestamp. You can use mutateRowWithTs() method. Which expects a timestamp as a parameter. 2 columns with same timestamp are added.

Comment: OK. But if I accidentally executed three writes to a given cell all with the same version during which time no flushes have occurred. Which of the three data writes will dBase
maintain?

Comment: It maintains the first write. Subsequent updates to the cell in the same batch will be dropped.

Comment: Hi, I got the answer to my question.It maintains the last version of write .
"Make sure to avoid collisions by using the same value for two separate updates to the same cell. Usually the last saved value is visible afterward"

Reference :Hbase Definitive Guide